# Not able to fetch the static dropdown value using codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a blog page which needs to be updated but unable to fetch the dropdown value from database.Here is the code for fetching dropdown value from database.While adding the data it is inserting successfully but while fetching the data to edit it is not working.Thanks In Advance

View:

```
<?php if(isset($records) && is_array($records) && count($records)>0): ?>
            <?php foreach($records as $r):?>
<?php
        $form_attributes  = array('name'=>'edit', 'id'=>'edit', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
        echo form_open('blogs/editblogs',$form_attributes);
        echo form_hidden('blog_id',$r->blog_id);
    ?>      
    <div class="element">
        <label for="positions"><font color="black">Position</font></label>
        <select name="position">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">Select none</option>              
        </select>
    </div>  
    <?php echo form_close();?>
    <?php endforeach;endif;?>
```

Controller:

```
function editblogs()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="message error"> ','</span>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('position','Position');
    if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
    {         
        $data['records']=$this->blogs_model->getblogsdata($this->input->post('blog_id'));
        $data['mainpage']='blogs';
        $data['mode']='edit';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);  
    }   
        else    
        {       
            $result = $this->blogs_model->update($this->input->post('blog_id'));        
            if(is_array($result))
            {       
                $data['errors']=$result;
                $data['records']=$this->blogs_model->getblogsdata($this->uri->segment('blog_id'));             
                $data['mainpage']='blogs';
                $data['mode']='edit';
                $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);  
            }                              
                else                    
                $this->flash->success('<h2>Successfully Updated the record.<h2>');                      
                redirect('blogs');                  
        }                       
}
```

Model:

```
function update($id)
{
    $data=array(
    'position'=>$this->input->post('position')
    );
    $this->db->where(array('blog_id'=>$id));
    $this->db->update('blogs', $data);
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: Anyone help me this.Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please explain  'fetch the dropdown value from database'. Canot find a dropdown based on the database.

Comment: @VivekShah it is a static dropdown while adding any data it is inserting the value successfully but how to fetch the data to show the value while editing

Comment: Ok so your actual question is how to show those value stored in database to this form?

Comment: @VivekShah yes i need to fetch that dropdown value from database and show when i edit the form

Comment: Anyone who can help me this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching the value from database for static dropdown. Here is the answer.

```
<div class="element">
        <label for="positions"><font color="black">Position</font></label>
        <?php
            $selected = ($this->input->post('position')) ? $this->input->post('position') : $r->position; ;  
            $position = array("1" => "1", "2" => "2", "3" => "3", "4" => "Select none");
            echo form_dropdown('position', $position, $selected);
        ?>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this below one
Please try the below code

```
    <?php if(isset($records) && is_array($records) && count($records)>0): ?>
            <?php foreach($records as $r):?>
<?php
        $form_attributes  = array('name'=>'edit', 'id'=>'edit', 'enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
        echo form_open('blogs/editblogs',$form_attributes);
        echo form_hidden('blog_id',$r->blog_id);
    ?>      
    <div class="element">
        <label for="positions"><font color="black">Position</font></label>
        <select name="position">
          <?php for($i=1;i<3;i++)
          $option = '<option value="'.$i.'"';
          if($i === $r->position ){
            $option .= 'selected';
          }
          $option .= '>'.$i.'</option>';

          <?php?>
          <option value="4">Select none</option>              
        </select>
    </div>  
    <?php echo form_close();?>
    <?php endforeach;endif;?>
```

Comment: not able to load the page getting error as page is not working

Comment: Getting error as page is not working that it not getting any error

Comment: The www.website.com page isn’t working

www.website.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Do you get value of records?

Comment: I am not able to open that page itself if i am adding the code which you sent